# make array<Promise> to an array without Promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Now I have an array with four promises like this:

```
fieldsForSave:  [ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
```

Now I just can get each one of four

```
fieldsForSave.map(async (promise) => {
        let result = await promise;
        console.log(result);//for example result is { field: 5b1c4558337f87fa32aec69c, isRequired: true }
      });
```

How can I get the resolves like this, I want to use this array to update mongoose schema.

```
fieldsForSave:  [ { field: 5b1c4558337f87fa32aec69b, isRequired: true }
{ field: 5b1c4558337f87fa32aec69c, isRequired: true }
{ field: 5b1c4558337f87fa32aec69d, isRequired: true }
{ field: 5b1c4558337f87fa32aec69e, isRequired: true } ]
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you want without promise? promise.all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to get one promise out of multiple promises:

```
let results = await Promise.all(fieldsForSave);
console.log(results);
```